# For each list, count the total number of elements with matching class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out and researching for an answer, but none of the answers I've found take into consideration counting each list. I need something that can count the total number of elements with class "link" inside **each** element with class "nav". I need that number stored as a variable so I can to add a new class to the "nav" elements depending on range qualifiers.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link">
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link"></li>
    <li class="link">
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="link">
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li class="link"></li>
            <li class="link"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Count them and then do what with the count? Because the counting part is - despite your difficulties - easy (when you know how); what you're then needing to do dictates what *we* need to show you how to accomplish and demonstrate.

Comment: Also, as an addendum, you've not shown any of the code that you've tried, or explained how that code failed (please see the "[mcve]," and "[ask]," guidelines for specific advice). So, currently, it's difficult to answer your question in any meaningful way (because it's hard to see what you're actually *asking*).

Comment: do you need nested `link` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around this morning (and before loading StackOverflow), I was finally able to develop this answer:

```
$('.nav').each(function(){
    var numLinks = $(this).find('.link').length;
    if (numLinks > 40) {
        $(this).addClass('mm-5-cols');
    } else if (numLinks > 30 && numLinks <= 40) {
        $(this).addClass('mm-4-cols');
    } else if (numLinks > 20 && numLinks <= 30) {
        $(this).addClass('mm-3-cols');
    } else if (numLinks > 10 && numLinks <= 20) {
        $(this).addClass('mm-2-cols');
    } else if (numLinks <= 10) {
        $(this).addClass('mm-1-col');
    }
});
```

(Apologies if the solution code is slightly off. I modified it from my actual code to match my example code.)

Thanks to those that answered with their own code!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var items = $.map( $(".nav"), function(navEl) {
    return [navEl, navEl.find(".link").length];
});

console.log( items );
```

I'm using `jQuery.map()` to construct a new array based on the `.nav` elements  - each element in the constructed array is array by its own: the first index is the jQuery object, and the second is the count of its children's `.link` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to count the number of elements with class `link` inside each element with class `nav`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').find('.nav').each(function(){
        sum = 0;
        $(this).find('.link').each(function(){
        sum=sum+1;
        });
        console.log(sum);
    });
});
```